# Is it possible to obtain a chain map from continuous to smooth "ordinary singular" chain complexes?

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, homology-cohomology

Let $X$ be a smooth manifold,
with $\mathbb{Z}$-coefficient singular chain complex $C_{\bullet}(X)$
and $C^{\text{sm}}_{\bullet}(X)$ the chain sub-complex consisting of *smooth* chains (i.e. having $C^{\text{sm}}_k$ = the subgrp generated by singular $k$-simplices whose corresponding maps into $X$ are smooth, i.e. have smooth extension on some neighborhood of $\Delta^k\subset\mathbb{R}^k$).

For each integer $k$, smooth approximation (and a choice function)
gives a function from continuous singular simplices to "smooth" simplices in $X$,
giving a homomorphism $C_{k}(X)\rightarrow C^{\text{sm}}_{k}(X)$, which I think we can likely take to be surjective.

My question is, is it possible to refine the above to a chain map (morphism of chain complexes) $C_{\bullet}(X)\rightarrow C^{\text{sm}}_{\bullet}(X)$?
I've been thinking about this with various arguments but I haven't managed to make a map commuting with $\partial$.

Comment: See Theorem 18.7 in my _Introduction to Smooth Manifolds_.

Comment: I think for arguments like this, it is common to use smooth approximation to argue that the map is a quasiisomorphism, then use the fact that both are chain complexes of free modules to invert the quasiisomorphism

Comment: Thank you both very much for your help!